# grpc server and gateway shutdown order

Tags: grpc-go, grpc-gateway, graceful-shutdown

my gRPC service uses [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) to serve http requests.

in order to make the service shutdown gracefully, is there an order i need to pay attention to? i.e. is the shutdown order

A. gRPC service -> gateway

B. gateway -> gRPC service

the only article/document i can find is [here](http://www.codershaven.com/graceful-shutdown-of-a-go-service/), which recommend A but didn't explain why. my own reasoning for A would be we need the gateway to be alive to route the outstanding gRPC requests. but that's not supported by any documentation.

Comment: grpc gateway is just a proxy over grpc,  I believe one should stop the grpc server before shutting down the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

from this link you've shared is not clear the motivation of shutdown first grpc service and them rest gateway.

But here is my reasons I gracefully shutdown first rest gateway:

- rest gateway depends on grpc service
- shutdown grpc do not wait for rest processing its stuff (it causes errors) and 503 responses. (specifically to me it causes bad results on my SLOs metics)